# Why is dotnet spawning multiple processes on Linux?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I run an asp.net core 3.0 application by `dotnet app.dll` on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.
I see 13 processes of my app. Why does it happen?[image: 13processes of Asp .net core]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The white value in the list are the main processes. The green values are the threads.

This will probably be easier to visually parse if you enable the tree view.

You can do this via `F2` -> `Display Options` -> Check `Tree View`

Also, from the `Display Options` Menu, you can change or disable the appearance of threads.

---

Another stack overflow thread provides more detail here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps